# How to find $Dim(W_{1}\cap W_{2}\cap W_{3})$, for given $9$ dimension sub spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am asking this question with reference to this previously asked question 
[$Dim(W_{1}\cap W_{2}\cap W_{3})$, for given $9$ dimension sub spaces $W_{1},W_{2}$ and $W_{3}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{10}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065003/dimw-1-cap-w-2-cap-w-3-for-given-9-dimension-sub-spaces-w-1-w-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In the answer provided by one of the user s(he) claims  that $dim W$ cannot  be less than 8.

But I am not able to follow the logic given . Can anyone explain it  to me clearly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely just a typo or a misreading, for a basis $B=\{e_1,\ldots,e_{10}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ we can take $W_i$ to be generated by $B\setminus\{e_i\}$, then $W$ is generated by $\{e_4,\ldots,e_{10}\}$ and so is of dimension $7$.

Their argument in fact shows that $\dim{W}\leq8$.

It can't be $10$ because $W\subseteq W_i$.

If it were $9$ then they would all be equal, because for any $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$, $i\neq j$, we have $W\subseteq W_i\cap W_j$, so $W_i\cap W_j$ must be of dimension $9$. Now, $W_i\cap W_j\subseteq W_i$, so if $W_i\cap W_j$ is also of dimension $9$ we would have $W_i=W_i\cap W_j$. Then $W_i\subseteq W_j$, so since it is also of dimension $9$ we would have $W_i=W_j$, contradicting distinctness.